# Adding value in loop of hash rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the empty hash  `@task_data =  Hash.new({task_name: '', updated_at: '', worked_by: ''})`

Now I want to loop around the variable and adding the value into the hash @task_data something like below

```
 i = 1     
    @tasks.each do |task|             
      @task_data[i][:task_name] = task.task_name
      @task_data[i][:update_at] = task.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")          
      if task.task_timings.present? && !task.task_timings.last.user_id.nil?
        @task_data[i][:worked_by] = task.task_timings.last.user.name
      else
        @task_data[i][:worked_by] = '' 
      end
      i = i+1
    end
  end
```

But when I displayed the value after the loop it's still empty.

I need something like `@task_data = {1 => {task_name: '', updated_at: '', worked_by: ''}, 2 => {task_name: '', updated_at: '', worked_by: ''}, 3 => {task_name: '', updated_at: '', worked_by: ''}}`

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has functional style for more readable notation (see `Enumerable#map`), also you can use safe navigation operator here:

```rb
@task_data = @tasks.map do |task|
  {
    task_name: task.task_name,
    update_at: task.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
    worked_by: task.task_timings.last&.user&.name || ''
  }
end.each.with_index(1).to_h{|task,index| [index, task]}
```

Comment: `.each.with_index(1).to_h.invert` has the chance to reduce the output count if two tasks are considered the same, since they will be used as key first. You could change this to `.each.with_index(1).to_h { |task, i| [i, task] }` to resolve this. Example `tasks = [{a: 1}, {a: 1}]` would produce `{2 => {a: 1}}` with the current solution.

Comment: Also `each.with_index(1).with_object({}) do |(task,idx),obj|` would make this a bit cleaner too then the loop would just be `obj[idx] = {
    task_name: task.task_name,
    update_at: task.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
    worked_by: task.task_timings.last&.user&.name || ''
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```rb
Hash[tasks.map.with_index(1) do |task, idx| 
  [idx, {task_name: task.task_name, updated_at: task.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), worked_by: task.task_timings.last.user.name}]
]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.